# Opening App in Other App

Tags: javascript, android, performance, algorithm

Is there a way for an app to open another up inside for android phones? There is this dot game for android phones and I want to be able to open it in another app.

Comment: Seems you are asking to completely different questions here? and you can launch one app from another using intents http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: so if I wrote an app I could open another one inside mine?

Comment: You may wish to explain what you mean by "inside", plus ask a separate SO question for the JavaScript part.

Comment: Indeed what do you mean by inside? you can launch an app from another app but it will open as its own app.

Comment: There's a game called dots, I want to be able to run an a algorithm (I think quick join or weighted quick union)on it to be able to beat the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, you cannot inject input events into arbitrary other applications, for obvious security reasons.